# php5.4 + freebsd8.3+nginx can't get errors

Tags: php, logging, nginx, freebsd

I have a confusing behaviour. I can't get any error into log file or screen.

 I made a file index.php with content like this: 
"<?php a();".Normally, I will get message like this: "Call to undefined function a()" but when I called this script on my configuration I got nothing. Only white screen and empty logs. 
I checked all rights. I turned on all possible log file. Nothing. Please help me.

My configuration is:
**freebsd 8.3-RELEASE**
**PHP 5.4.7 (fpm-fcgi)**
**nginx version: nginx/1.2.4**

**FPM-config**

```
[global]
pid = run/php-fpm.pid
error_log = log/php-fpm.log
log_level = notice
emergency_restart_threshold = 5
emergency_restart_interval = 2
process_control_timeout = 2
daemonize = yes
events.mechanism = kqueue

[puser]
listen = /usr/local/www/host/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
listen.backlog = -1
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.owner = puser
listen.group = puser
listen.mode = 0666
user = puser
group = puser
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 30
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_requests = 50
slowlog = /usr/local/www/host/logs/fpm.log.slow
request_slowlog_timeout = 1s
rlimit_files = 1024
rlimit_core = 0
chroot = /usr/local/www/host/
catch_workers_output = yes
env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
env[TMP] =    /tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
env[TEMP] =   /tmp
php_admin_value[upload_tmp_dir] = /tmp
php_admin_value[cgi.fix_pathinfo] = 0
php_admin_value[date.timezone]= 'Europe/Moscow'
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 320m
php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 180
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log]  = /logs/fpm-err.log
php_admin_value[error_reporting] = 'E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE'
php_admin_value[display_errors] = on
php_admin_flag[display_startup_errors] = on
```

**NGINX config**

```
user  www;
worker_processes  2;
worker_rlimit_nofile 80000;

error_log  /var/log/nginx_error.log  notice;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  2048;
    use kqueue;
}

http {
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 4m;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    charset utf-8;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    log_format IP .$remote_addr.;
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request $request_body '
'"$status" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;

  access_log /usr/local/www/host/logs/access.log main;
  error_log  /usr/local/www/host/logs/error.log error;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /errors/50x.html;
  error_page 404  /errors/404.html;
  root /usr/local/www/host/htdocs;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;


  location / {
        index  index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

   location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/www/host/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   /htdocs$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  /htdocs$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}

}
```

**PHP config** (php.ini)

```
[PHP]
engine = On
short_open_tag = On
asp_tags = Off
precision = 14
y2k_compliance = On
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = 100
allow_call_time_pass_reference = Off
safe_mode = Off
safe_mode_gid = Off
safe_mode_include_dir =
safe_mode_exec_dir =
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
disable_functions = dl,system,exec,passthru,shell_exec
disable_classes =
expose_php = On
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = On
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm-error.log
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_globals = Off
register_long_arrays = Off
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 8M
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
doc_root =
user_dir =
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_file_uploads = 20
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60
[Date]
date.timezone = Europe/Moscow
[filter]
[iconv]
[intl]
[sqlite]
[sqlite3]
[Pcre]
[Pdo]
[Pdo_mysql]
[Phar]
[Syslog]
define_syslog_variables  = Off
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
mail.add_x_header = On
[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off
[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
[Interbase]
[MySQL]
mysql.allow_local_infile = On
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.cache_size = 2000
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port =
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off
[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off
[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off
[OCI8]
[PostgresSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0
[Sybase-CT]
sybct.allow_persistent = On
sybct.max_persistent = -1
sybct.max_links = -1
sybct.min_server_severity = 10
sybct.min_client_severity = 10
[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0
[browscap]
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = Off
session.bug_compat_warn = Off
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
[MSSQL]
mssql.allow_persistent = On
mssql.max_persistent = -1
mssql.max_links = -1
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
mssql.min_message_severity = 10
mssql.compatability_mode = Off
mssql.secure_connection = Off
[Assertion]
[COM]
[mbstring]
[gd]
[exif]
[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off
[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
[sysvshm]
[ldap]
ldap.max_links = -1
[mcrypt]
[dba]
```

I need to get errors on display and detailed record in the error.log.

Comment: Did you try making a script with a call to phpinfo() in it, checking the output and looking at the error_reporting and display_errors settings?

Comment: Yes.
    `display_errors On`
    `error_reporting E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`

Answer (score 1):

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
```

Is this the culprit?

Also,, have you tried:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the top of your PHP scripts?

Comment: I solve this problem.
php_admin_value[error_reporting] = 'E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE'

Looks normal huh?
But I found remark in documentation about quots. Do not use the quots.
It breaks error logging and error displaying.

Working string looks like
php_admin_value[error_reporting] = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE